# Symfony 2 controller is not callable?

Tags: symfony

Symfony is throwing this exception when accessing its associated URI:

> Controller
>   "Backend\ChatBundle\Controller\DefaultController::generateAction" for
>   URI "/chat/generate/2" is not callable.

This is the relevant controller code:

```
/**
 * Class DefaultController
 * @package Backend\ChatBundle\Controller
 * @Route("/chat")
 */
class DefaultController extends BaseController
{

/**
 * @Route("/generate/{id}", requirements={"id":"\d+"}, name="backend_chat_default_create")
 */
public function generateAction(User $user)
{
```

I tried to clear the cache directory and change the name of the method and route to no avail.

Comment: could you show the route file ?

Comment: @kpk http://pastebin.com/jgcpK5V8

Comment: Could it be that you're defining a prefix both in youre DefaultController (/chat) and in your routing file (/)?

Comment: use `php app/console debug:router` (or `php app/console router:debug` in previous versions) to view available routes

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/jgcpK5V8 line no 4 and 12 have the same `prefix /`. This is the issue. You could change the line no 4 `prefix : /chat`. 
You cannot give the same `/` same prefix to more than one controller.
**Edit:**
note the route name is just "backend_chat" which is specified in the route file.

```
class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/chat/generate/{id}", requirements={"id":"\d+"}, name="backend_chat") 
     */
    public function generateAction(User $user)
    {
        // some code here
    }
```

in your route file add like this

```
backend_chat:
    path:     /chat
    defaults: { _controller: DemoDemoBundle:Default:generate }
```

Comment: here `/` is the root.

Comment: But if I change "/" - "/chat" and remove @Route("/chat") in the controller this not solved my problem, controller is not callable.
If I don't remove annotation Route in the controller SF return me 404.

Comment: you have given the route name `name="backend_chat_default_create"` , but in rounting.yml file its just `backend_chat` this is also a reason. Make sure the Route name is same as in routing file and in controller methods. The path and the name is different !

Comment: I wanna use only annotation, I can't use yaml syntax for routing path and setting controllers.

Comment: just change the name in the controller `name="backend_chat_default_create"` as same as the rout you gave in the routing file ! The routing file you shared is yml. So the code i mentioned will work. Read the Docs for reference !

Comment: I do not understad what you mean...
If i set name route for chat controller "backend_chat" I should set name route in the generateAction and more actions of controller name is "backend_chat"? Not "backend_chat_generate" and more?

Comment: the controller is annotation, there you should specify the route name which is same as the name you gave in the routing yml file.

Comment: If you use CRUD then you can specify the Route as `resource` in your routing file. But if you use your own names like generate then you should specify the path and controller action ! like i said above !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104287/discussion-between-kpk-and-daniel-andreyev).